# More stable algorithm to calculate `sqrt(a^2 + b^2) - abs(a)` in MatLab

Tags: matlab, numerics, algorithms

Suppose we want to calculate $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-|a|$ in MatLab. Using `sqrt(a^2 + b^2) - abs(a)` will have some problems:

- If `a` or `b` are too large, it may cause overflow
- if `a` and `b` are too small, it may cause underflow
- if `a>>b`, `a^2 + b^2` may be equal to `a^2` in machine

What's a more stable algorithm to calculate this without leading to overflow, underflow or omitting `b^2`?

First thing that came to my mind was to use `if` clauses that if one error is going to happen, then stop. But I think there can be a way to calculate the answer anyway, because we don't need `a^2` or `b^2`, we need `sqrt(a^2 + b^2) - abs(a)`. But I couldn't find a way to do the calculation when for example `b` is too large. Second thing that came to my mind was to change the formula. I only could reach `sqrt((a + b)^2 - 2*a*b) - abs(a)` and couldn't expand the formula anymore. This would help in 3rd problem case, but won't help overflow or underflow I think. Any help is so much appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can break down the domain of your function into three distinct cases:

- $|a|\gg |b|$: In this case, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \approx |a|$ and a naive application of the formula will likely result in poor accuracy. But you can transform
  $$
  \sqrt{a^2+b^2} - |a| = \sqrt{a^2(1+b^2/a^2)} - |a| = |a| \left(\sqrt{1+b^2/a^2}-1\right)
  $$
  and at this point you use a Taylor expansion. To first order, because $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+\frac{1}{2}x$ for small $x$, you get
  $$
  \sqrt{a^2+b^2} - |a| \approx|a| \left(\frac 12 b^2/a^2\right)
  = \frac{b^2}{2|a|}.
  $$
  If you want better accuracy, you can always higher order Taylor expansions.
- $|a|\ll|b|$: This also results in poor accuracy because the effect of $a$ is lost. But again we can do the following:
  $$
  \sqrt{a^2+b^2} - |a| = \sqrt{b^2(1+a^2/b^2)} - |a| = |b|\left(\sqrt{1+a^2/b^2} - \frac{|a|}{|b|}\right).
  $$
  By the same Taylor expansion, you can approximate
  $$
  \sqrt{a^2+b^2} - |a| \approx
  |b|\left(1+\frac{a^2}{2b^2} - \frac{|a|}{|b|}\right).
  $$
  This can again be stably evaluated in terms of the small parameter $a/b$. As before, you can use a higher order Taylor approximation.
- $|a|\approx |b|$: In this case, the two quantities are approximately the same and no truncation error should happen when evaluating the original formula.

Answer (score 25):

A manipulation that may help is the following. Assume for simplicity $a>0$. We have the identity
$$b^2 = (a^2+b^2)-a^2 = (\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a)(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a),$$
hence
$$
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a = \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a},
$$
and the cancellation is gone.

Note that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ can be computed without the overflow associated to squaring with `hypot(a,b)`. If one rearranges the computation as `(b / (hypot(a,b)+a)) * b` I think that most of your corner cases are solved. The only danger is that `hypot(a,b)+a` may overflow, but that will happen only if $a,b$ are of the order of $10^{300}$.

EDIT: you may be interested in checking out methods for computing accurate solutions to scalar quadratic equations. This is a closely related problem, as one encounters similar issues when computing the numerator of the classical formula $b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}$;  and indeed your problem can be reformulated as finding the positive solution of the quadratic equation $x^2 + 2ax - b^2=0$. For instance, there is [this note](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/Qdrtcs.pdf) by one of the founding fathers of floating-point computing, and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979861/numerically-stable-method-for-solving-quadratic-equations) with useful algorithms.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was awesome. But I was looking for methods that do not use functions like `hypot(a, b)` as I have some limits at the moment. But It'll be really useful to me in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: @IlkayBurak This answer is brilliant and does not really force you to use `hypot` in any way. That's just his suggestion to avoid overflows. If you want, you can actually copy the implementation of `hypot` from an (appropriately-licensed) open source language into your own code since the implementation is quite simple. Alternatively, you can also use a cases based solution and approximations as in @WolfgangBangerth's good answer.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, there's no need to assume positive $a$: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-|a| = \frac{(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-|a|)(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+|a| )}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+|a|}=\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+|a|}$

Comment: @LucaCiti I agree; that assumption is just there to save a few absolute values and have simpler-looking formulas.

Comment: Sure, I understand. However my derivation is equally simple, just requiring multiplying and dividing by the same quantity and then noticing that you obtain a sum times a difference of two terms, which is a difference of squares. Then it's easy from there.

Answer (score 5):

This is basically a variant of Federico Poloni's excellent [answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/43415/20458), based on the principle that one might want to try proven building blocks first. I do not know if Matlab provides this functionality, but various computational platforms offer a function `sqrt1pm1()`, which computes $\sqrt{x+1}-1$ accurately while avoiding subtractive cancellation. This is an excellent building block for situations like this one. Where a function `sqrt1pm1()` is not provided, we could easily build it ourselves:

```c
/* compute sqrt (x+1)-1 */
double sqrt1pm1 (double a) { 
    return a / (1 + sqrt (a + 1)); 
}
```

With this building block, the computation from the question turns into:

```c
/* compute sqrt(a**2 + b**2) - |a| */
double func (double a, double b) 
{
    double ratio = b / a;
    return fabs (a) * sqrt1pm1 (ratio * ratio);
}
```

While this addresses accuracy issues arising from subtractive cancellation, it does *not* address all potential issues of potential overflow and underflow in intermediate computation. In particular it lacks the range-mitigating effect provided by the use of `hypot()`. Obviously this approach also requires that $a \ne 0$, but $a=0$ is easily handled separately.